# How can I access variable from another class?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I have made an object of my class Commands

```
Commands commands = new Commands();
```

but, I need to access the array inside that method, not sure how to do it.

### Player.java

```
package com.PenguinGaming;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

public void User(){

    Commands commands = new Commands();

    int Maxlife = 25;
    int life = 25;
    int turns = 0;

    //Starting player location
    int playerX = 4;
    int playerY = 4;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = null;


    while(life > 1){

        System.out.println("Player life: " + life + "/" + Maxlife);
        input = scanner.nextLine();
        input = input.toLowerCase();

        life -= 1;

        for(int i = 0; i == 30; i++){
            turns++;
            if(turns == 30){
                Maxlife += 5;
            }
        }

        if (input.equals(commands[0])) {
        // give description for player location
        System.out.println(locations[playerX][playerY]);
        }

        if(input.equals(commands[1])){
            //Go north
            System.out.println(locations[playerX][playerY+1]);
            playerY += 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands[2])){
            //Go east
            System.out.println(locations[playerX+1][playerY]);
            playerX += 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands[3])){
            //Go south
            System.out.println(locations[playerX][playerY-1]);
            playerY -= 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands[4])){
            //Go west
            System.out.println(locations[playerX-1][playerY]);
            playerX -= 1;
        }

        if(input.equals(commands[5])){
            break;
        }

        if(life <= 0){
            System.out.println("Looks like you have starved, better luck next game");
            break;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("You can not move in that direction");

    }
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

### Commands.java

```
package com.PenguinGaming;

public class Commands {

/*
 * Command list:
 * - investigate (advanced description)
 * - go north
 * - go south
 * - go west
 * - go east
 * - pick up
 * - eat
 * - drink from
 * - drink object
 * - climb up/down
 * - burn
 * - use object
 * - attack
 * - defend
 * - description (basic description)
 * - read
 * - life
 * - help (brings up command list)
 */

public void commandlist(){

    String[] commands = new String[6];
    commands[0] = "investigate";
    commands[1] = "go north";
    commands[2] = "go east";
    commands[3] = "go south";
    commands[4] = "go west";
    commands[5] = "terminate game";
}

}
```

Comment: You want to access `commands` in `commandlist()`? Change the return type to `String[]` and return `commands`.

Comment: Thank you August, it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Don't you want your commands to exist somewhere permanently? Do you have to create that String[] every time somebody needs list of command? Will it ever change? If not, then make it private static final and write getter method that returns commands.

Comment: there's also a convention of naming packages to be all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clean your code up a little bit you can do something like this:

```
public String[] commandlist()
{
  return new String[]{"investigate", "go north", "go east", "go south", "go west", "terminate game"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has already way of storing well defined set of constant values. It's called [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

```
public enum Commands {
    INVESTIGATE("investigate"),
    GO_NORTH("go north"),
    GO_EAST("go east"),
   ...

}
```

and so on.

This way you can import Commands to class you write and get all  of its values by `Commands.values()` that returns set, so you can iterate over it, whatever you want. This way if you find a need of adding another command you have to do it in one place only because you operate on, check for equality on those values, etc.

I forgot to mention that by doing so, you don't have to create object Commands manually.